# Cambiar un dato en un archivo.DAT

Tags: php, python, estructuras-de-datos, datos

Quiero cambiar parte de este archivo:

> 0.2482,200.52,25,0.59
> 4,0,0
> 1E0,0 ,1e-5  ,1E3   ,1E2   ,1E-5
> 2.5E0 ,0 ,1e-5 ,1E3   ,1E2   ,1E-5
> 2.3E0 ,0 ,1e-5  ,1E3   ,1E2   ,1E-5
> 1.4E0 ,0 ,1e-5  ,1E3   ,1E2   ,1E-5
> 1000,2
> 0.40,0.059160

Este archivo es un **`.DAT`** y estoy intentado cambiar uno de los datos el **`200.52`** por una variable llamada *volumen_botella* la variable es de tipo *float* también.

Código:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\QUIMA\\Desktop\\alca\\GUESSM1.DAT','r+') as f:
    lines = list(f)
    lines[0]=0.2482,(float(volumen_botella)),25,0.59
    
    str(lines)
    tt=" ".join(map(str,lines))
    f.write(tt)
```

El problema es que no me puede cambiar lo de dentro de ese archivo, tiene que tener el mismo formato. Cuando ejecuto eso me sale esta salida:

> (0.2482, 134.03, 25, 0.59),4,0,0
> ,1E0,0 ,1e-5  ,1E3   ,1E2   ,1E-5
> ,2.5E0 ,0 ,1e-5 ,1E3   ,1E2   ,1E-5
> ,2.3E0 ,0 ,1e-5  ,1E3   ,1E2   ,1E-5
> ,1.4E0 ,0 ,1e-5  ,1E3   ,1E2   ,1E-5
> ,1000,2
> ,0.40,0.059160

Al cambiar no me sirve. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Siempre será el valor 200.52? O en general es reemplazar el segundo valor de la primer línea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer lo que pides primero tendremos que leer el archivo, luego escoger la linea y por ultimo, escoger el elemento a reemplazar y finalmente escribimos en el archivo

```py
with open('ruta.DAT','r+') as f: #el r+ significa lectura y escritura
    lineas = f.readlines() #leemos las lineas
```

Al leer por líneas nos devuelve una lista y cada elemento representa una linea, pero la linea sale algo así `['0.2482,200.52,25,0.59\n',...]`, aquí podemos hacer 2 cosas, 1) reemplazar la linea entera (no recomendado si los datos son variables) y 2) cambiar solo el dato que nos interesa, en este caso opte por la segunda opcion, para debemos convertir cada linea (elemento de la lista) en una nueva lista, esto lo hacemos con un `split(',')`, lo que separara la cadena por cada coma (`,`) que encuentre.

```
    ...
    lineas = [dato.split(',') for dato in lineas] 

    volumen_botella = 134.03 #definimos la variable

    lineas[0][1] = f"{volumen_botella}" #reemplazamos el valor
```

En este punto ya podríamos escribir el nuevo dato, pero ¿Cómo?, si hacemos `f.write(lineas)` nos dara un error puesto que la variable `lineas` es una lista con listas, y debería ser solo una lista con sus elementos, otra cosa que pasara, sera que el contenido se escribirá debajo del que ya existe, mas no se reemplazara.

Para solucionar el primero problema, convertimos la lista en una cadena con la función `join()` lo que nos devolverá una lista con elementos como `['0.2482,134.03,25,0.59\n',...]` (con el dato cambiado).
Luego tendremos que movernos al principio del archivo, por defecto estamos al final, por eso los datos se escriben de nuevo. Al movernos al principio con `seek()` vamos a escribir los datos de nuevo (o sobrescribir)

```py
    ...  
    s = f.seek(0,0) #nos movemos al principio
    lineas = [",".join(dato) for dato in lineas] #convertimos las listas a cadenas
    f.writelines(lineas)#escribimos
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Christian. Llevo dos días con esto porque si que me lo cambiaba pero no dejaba la misma estructura el archivo.Gracias.

Comment: @Adrián de nada :)